# How can I fix this inline-block alignment problem on my Woocommerce site?

Tags: css, woocommerce

Trying to wrangle some css and I need a bit of guidance. I am displaying the amount of product reviews on our shop page, but the number of reviews displays under the star rating. I'm trying to get the number of reviews to display next to the star rating. The alignment is coming up weird.

I have tried the following snippet:

```css
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .star-rating,
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .woocommerce-review-link {
  display:inline-block
  }
```

The number of reviews and the star rating do not line up nicely. Image attached.

[Website](https://www.fralinpickups.com/shop/)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7rIj.png)

[image]
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbKIc.png)

[image]

Comment: um cant see the image

Comment: Sorry, fixed...

Comment: Hmm the website isnt loading so from the top of my head, why not give a min-height to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no access to the markup, the easiest way is to use `position: relative` and adjust it's top value:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .star-rating {
    display:inline-block;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .woocommerce-review-link {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks so much!

Comment: So I need a bit more information...Some reviews are 'inline' with the product H2 description. How can I make it so every review lays underneath the product description?

Comment: You have situations where the markup is different? Can you post an image of the other case?

Comment: See the original post for 'Screenshot 2'. Webpage is [link] (https://www.fralinpickups.com/shop/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I set the H2 Width to 100% and that solved it. Thanks for all your help!